# How would you #include multiple .h files to prevent warnings

Tags: c, include, include-path, gcc-warning

I have a single main .c file with 4 .h files and .c files included into the main function.  Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
#include "file3.h"
#include "file4.h"

int main(){...}
```

The .h files have all the declarations for all of their corresponding .c files.  Some of the .c files do use functions from other .c files, for example "file4.c" uses some functions declared in "file2.h" and "file1.c" uses functions declared in "file3.h".  I've tried declaring the same includes as in main in every .c file and tried reordering the include files, but I still get warning messages about implicit declarations of functions and incompatible implicit declarations.

I was wondering how you would use #includes in your large projects to eliminate  warning messages.  I'm using gcc as the compiler.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125542/how-can-i-split-up-my-monolithic-programs-into-smaller-separate-files

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard?

Comment: Perhaps you should post an example warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you want import the **.h** file in a part of main() file, you must sure that you didn't import it anywhere.
For example: 
**file4.h** use functions in **file3.h**
If you imported **file3.h** in file **file4.h** you have to not import **file3.h** in file **main()**. It's the duplicated definition.
If you have a lot of init files. You can import it in the only general file. And use that file in **main()**.
Hope you like it ^^

Comment: So you're saying that I should only import other files in main?  Wouldn't that mean that if I didn't include the .h files in the right order I would still get warnings?

Comment: I mean you should import all .h file in the only init file by some way. And use that init file int main as only file.h That makes your project clearly

Answer (score -1):

Try this on all your own head files:

```
(beginning of your head file)
#ifndef   _HEAD_FILE_NAME_H
#define _HEAD_FILE_NAME_H
...
<your headfile contents>
...

#endif
(end of your headfile)
```

Comment: I have something similar, I'll try this and see what happens.

Comment: I still have lots of warning messages after doing this.  Thanks though.